# ImageDataGenerator not found in keras's API Documentation

Tags: python, keras

Im following a Udemy course thats making use of ImageDataGenerator class of keras.preprocessing.image

In the course video (recorded in 2017) the API page definitely shows the class, but I cant find its documentation today despite me still being able to use the class itself.

After some search, I was able to come across its documentation on the Japanese page of Keras.

Heres the original Keras page: https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/
And hers its Japanese version: https://keras.io/ja/preprocessing/image/

Any idea what happened and how can I access its english documentation?

Comment: Does this help you? [https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator)

Comment: @Cuartero Yes! thank you so much! May I ask why the keras page differs from the tf.keras one?

Comment: @ArmenHaddad Because Keras used to be an external API. Since Tensorflow 2, Keras is implemented into Tensorflow as a backend, hence `tf.keras`.

Comment: Since many versions ago, keras has been included in the "tensorflow package". I don't know if now keras only keeps its documentation updated on the tensorflow page and that's why the keras domain is outdated for new versions of the API.